# check whether entered data is string or digit on VB 2010

Tags: vb.net

I wrote a program to check the format of an entered ID and if the format isn't correct I was to print "invalid".

The format is:"Dog123". The first letter was to be capital the second two lower case and the third digits.

I wrote a short one on Visual Basic 2010 just to check the first letter using ASCII values but it isn't working.

```
  Sub Main()
        Dim ID As String
        Dim FL As String
        Dim CORRECT As Boolean
        CORRECT = 0
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Identitfication")
        ID = Console.ReadLine
        FL = Left(ID, 1)
        If FL = FL >= Asc("A") Then
            If FL = FL <= Asc("Z") Then
                CORRECT = 1
                Console.WriteLine("Valid")
            End If
        End If
        If CORRECT = 0 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid")
        End If
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
```

Can someone please tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: What is this logic supposed to be: `If FL = FL >= Asc("A")`  How can a string be greater than or less than something?  Why = first, then >=?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on this line ` If FL = FL >= Asc("A") Then` and see if it is doing what you think it is doing.

Comment: im so sorry for sounding like an idiot but i just started programming and i have no idea what im doing. And also whats a breakpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following using Char.Is methods for first three characters then last three we ask Integer.TryParse to validate we have a int.

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim ID As String
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Identitfication")
        ID = Console.ReadLine
        If ID.Length = 6 Then
            If Char.IsUpper(ID(0)) AndAlso
                Char.IsLower(ID(1)) AndAlso
                Char.IsLower(ID(2)) AndAlso
                Integer.TryParse(ID.Substring(3, 3), Nothing) Then

                Console.WriteLine("Good to go")

            Else
                Console.WriteLine("Bad 2")
            End If
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Bad 1")
        End If
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Why you use boolean data type as integer you should use it like this

   Correct = True
2. You can replace the nested if with **AndAlso** so your code would be

   If FL >= Asc("A") AndAlso FL <=        Asc("Z") Then ...

3.you have checked only the first char and you must check the second and the  third and the digits

4. What you must delete FL = FL
5. You can replace the code **FL = Left(ID,1)** with FL = ID(0)

Comment: i know i have to check the rest of them as well. i just wanted to check the first one to see if i was doing it right. but thank you

Comment: I'd really just suggest to use a Regex for this.

Comment: @CFrozenDeth. I think RegEx is the best choise but not for a beginner

Comment: If I had any idea what Regex was maybe I'd be using it too

Comment: I made all the modifications and I'm just getting Invalid irrespective of what I enter @abdallahesam

Comment: @SevenDevils. From my prespective your way is the best for you cause it is will teach you how to deal with strings .

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of validation, you should look into RegEx (Regular Expression). You build a pattern like you did:

> The first letter was to be capital the second two lower case and the third digits.

and then, you test your strings against it.

Here's a tool to test your pattern : http://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

I would use regex to find out if my id matched.

You must `Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions`

```
Sub Main()

    Console.WriteLine("Enter Identitfication")
    Dim ID As String = Console.ReadLine

    If Regex.IsMatch(ID, "[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2}\d{3}") Then
        Console.WriteLine("Valid")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid")
    End If

    Console.ReadKey()


End Sub
```

The above regex checks to make sure:

1. Character at position 1 matches [A-Z], uppercase
2. Next next two characters match [a-z], lowecase
3. Next three characters are digits [\d]